# Orchard infinite scroll

Tags: orchardcms, infinite-scroll

I am trying to use an "Infinite Ajax Scrolling" Orchard module.

https://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.Orchard.jQuery.Ias

I installed the module through admin interface. I made necessary modifications described on the given link. Also, I had to do an extra modification that is described in the comments.

The infinite scrolling thing is just not functioning. I created about 30 blog posts in order to test it. When I scroll through blog posts through public website, first page og blog posts is loaded and when I scroll to the bottom, nothing happens. Pager is not visible (expected), but no new content is appended to the bottom of the list (not expected).

When I scroll through blog posts using Admin interface and I scroll down sufficiently, Chrome console reports couple of things:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en-US" class="static orchard-blogs"> 
<head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Proba - Manage Infinite Blog</title> 
    <link href="/OrchardLocal/Modul...<omitted>...l> jquery-1.9.1.js:4421
Sizzle.error jquery-1.9.1.js:4421
tokenize jquery-1.9.1.js:5076
select jquery-1.9.1.js:5460
Sizzle jquery-1.9.1.js:3998
jQuery.fn.extend.find jquery-1.9.1.js:5576
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init jquery-1.9.1.js:196
jQuery jquery-1.9.1.js:62
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init jquery-1.9.1.js:201
jQuery jquery-1.9.1.js:62
(anonymous function) jquery.ias.min.js:210
fire jquery-1.9.1.js:1037
self.fireWith jquery-1.9.1.js:1148
done jquery-1.9.1.js:8074
callback
```

A moment after:

```
GET http://localhost:30321/modules/orchard.jquery.ias/styles/images/loader.gif 404 (Not Found) jquery-1.9.1.js:6469
jQuery.extend.buildFragment jquery-1.9.1.js:6469
jQuery.extend.parseHTML jquery-1.9.1.js:531
jQuery.fn.jQuery.init jquery-1.9.1.js:149
jQuery jquery-1.9.1.js:62
get_loader jquery.ias.min.js:266
show_loader jquery.ias.min.js:279
paginate jquery.ias.min.js:167
scroll_handler jquery.ias.min.js:99
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-1.9.1.js:3074
elemData.handle jquery-1.9.1.js:2750
```

In the admin interface I checked Blog properties and it seems to be configured fine. All default values are in place for [Container, Item, Pager, NextAnchor], and these values are also present in the html file I'm viewing when reported errors occur.

### EDIT (after justrhysism's answer)

After implementing justrhysism's answer, I focused on why infinite scrolling works in the dashboard but not in front-end.
When I opened a list of blog posts in dashboard, I located .pager element.

```
<ul class="pager">
    <li class="first"><span>1</span></li>
    <li><a href="/OrchardLocal/Admin/Blogs/42?page=2">2</a></li>
    <li class="last"><a href="/OrchardLocal/Admin/Blogs/42?page=2">&gt;</a></li>
</ul>
```

I opened a list of blogs in front-end, and also located .pager element.

```
<ul class="pager" shape-id="92" style="display: none;">
    <li class="first" shape-id="92"><span shape-id="93">1</span></li>
    <li shape-id="92"><a href="/OrchardLocal/new-infinite-blog?page=2" shape-id="95">2</a></li>
    <li shape-id="92"><a href="/OrchardLocal/new-infinite-blog?page=2" shape-id="98">&gt;</a></li>
    <li class="last" shape-id="92"></li>
</ul>
```

Then I inspected javascript in charge for triggering async loading of content.

```
function paginate(curScrOffset, onCompleteHandler)
        {
            urlNextPage = $(opts.next).attr("href"); // evaluates to $(".zone-content .pager .last a").attr("href")
            ...............
        }
```

And found out that the *urlNextPage* variable always gets set to undefined in front-end view.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

I've come across this before. It's a document parsing error. There is a whitespace character (of some description) at the top of the document which Orchard returns instead of the `<!` which is expected. Somebody with more knowledge of AJAX and document parsing could better describe this.

**Solution**

To fix this, find the view `Document.cshtml` within Orchard's Core (located in `src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views`) and copy it to your Theme's View directory.

In this file, look to `Line 10` where `<!DOCTYPE html>` starts. Above this, remove the line break between the closing brace `}` and the DOCTYPE declaration.

*Before:*

```
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

*After:*

```
}<!DOCTYPE html>
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Cool. That fixed the error and infinite scrolling is now working in dashboard. Still not working in the front-end. Will try a bit more, now that you've helped me this far...

Comment: Fire up Fiddler and have a look at the response for the AJAX call. It's likely just a parsing error still, but Fiddler will help you identify where. Sometimes I also like to make an AJAX call directly through Chrome's console to see whether the error is server-side or client-side.

Answer (score 1):

The Infinite Ajax Scrolling module for Orchard CMS is on Github

https://github.com/grapto/js.Ias

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: You need to stipulate _why_ your answer should be considered and not just assume that any reader arriving on this page will know what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

In response to my last edit where *urlNextPage* was being set to undefined.

I changed the NextAnchor selector in Blog properties:
From default value of "`.zone-content .pager .last a`" ----> To "`.zone-content .pager a`".

Also I went into Orchard.jQuery.Ias module -> Scripts/jquery.ias.min.js

Changed paginate function.
Old:

```
function paginate(curScrOffset, onCompleteHandler)
        {
            urlNextPage = $(opts.next).attr("href");
            ....
```

New:

```
function paginate(curScrOffset, onCompleteHandler)
        {
            if ($(opts.pagination).find(".last span").length)
                return; // if span element exists in .last element, that means we are on the last page
            urlNextPage = $(opts.next).last().attr("href");
            ....
```

It works fine now, both in dashboard and in front-end. This is not a very reliable solution, because I made an assumption that last anchor tag in .pager will always lead to the next page. That assumption is based merely on my observations of module's behavior.